How can I write an order to search for the first engulfing candle 1 cell earlier
I have already set up the box before. I don't know how to check if the pair of candles touching the box first is the engulfing candle pair.
//@version=5
indicator("box", overlay = true)

spred= input.float(defval = 40, minval= 20, maxval= 100, title="Spred")

extendLeft  = input.bool(title="extend    ", defval=false, group="Cản", inline = "ON")

zone = input.color(color.rgb(13, 46, 231, 70), 'zonebuy', inline = '7')

skimb= close[2] < open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close > open and close[1] > open[2] and low > high[2]    and spbar1

var box[] skimbopen = array.new_box()

var box[] skimbclose = array.new_box()


if skimb and ofzone

   
   array.push(skimbopen, box.new(bar_index - 2,low[2], bar_index + 20, high[2], extend=extending, bgcolor=zone , border_width=0,
     text = 'oSK ', text_size = size.tiny, text_halign = text.align_right, text_color = color.white, text_font_family = font.family_monospace))

  
//---engufing ----conditon

   candle = close[1] < open[1] and close > open and close > open[1]


   if engul =  close[1] < top and close[1] > bottom


  Plotshapr ( engul , title="en "......)
          

I want to find a pair of candles like in the photo:


^ Please add the code to your question by editing it. You will need to use Markdown code formatting to make it readable.
